# Create subdomain on the fly Ubuntu 14.04 bind

Tags: bind

what I am trying to do is create a subdomain to a zone that already exist, but i get "update failed: SERVFAIL" error.

What I have so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash
record=yyy.mydomain.com
ttl=5
(
 echo "server localhost"
 echo "zone mydomain.com"

 echo "update add ${record} 300 A 217.x.x.x"
 echo "send"
) | /usr/bin/nsupdate
```

my zone config

```
zone "mydomain.com" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/zones/mydomain.com";
  allow-update {
    127.0.0.1;
    217.x.x.x;
   };
};
```

Does someone have any idea what am I missing

Comment: Does your BIND setup work other than this? Anything in the logs? What does `named-checkconf -zj` say?

Comment: It sounds unlikely that bind would be able to write to anything under `/etc/bind`. Normally you would have files that bind needs to write in `/var/lib/bind`, `/var/cache/bind` or similar depending on the situation. Is this perhaps the problem? (Logs should confirm if this is so)

Comment: named-checkconf -zj says : "zone mydomain.com/IN: loaded serial 7
"

Comment: omg, how did i miss this log: "17-Mar-2015 10:18:08.453 /etc/bind/zones/mydomain.com.jnl: create: permission denied" . Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem was because my zones were insite a "zones" folder, give permisions for the group to be able to write insite and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem is that `named` is unable to write to the path `/etc/bind/zones/mydomain.com` (and the associated `.jnl` file).

While it would be possible to simply make that path writable by the user which runs `named`, doing so would be somewhat unorthodox considering that this doesn't really fit with how `/etc` is normally used.

Generally services read their configuration from `/etc` but if a service is storing data somewhere those files would typically reside somewhere under `/var`.

While it is by no means universal or strictly adhered to, the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) may be a worthwhile read regarding the overall directory structure of UNIX-like operating systems.

The maintainers of the BIND packages in Ubuntu (Debian?) have documented their suggested configuration schema and directory structure, which is entirely along these lines.

Excerpt from `/usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz`:

> While you are free to craft whatever structure you wish for servers
>   which need to be authoritative for additional zones, what we suggest
>   is that you put the db files for any zones you are master for in
>   /etc/bind (perhaps even in a subdirectory structure depending on
>   complexity), using full pathnames in the named.conf file.  Any zones
>   you are secondary for should be configured in named.conf with simple
>   filenames (relative to /var/cache/bind), so the data files will be
>   stored in BIND's working directory (defaults to /var/cache/bind).
>   **Zones subject to automatic updates (such as via DHCP and/or nsupdate)
>   should be stored in /var/lib/bind, and specified with full pathnames.**

Comment: This is the correct answer for anyone running a modern Debian-based system with an AppArmor profile in “enforcement” mode. The default AppArmor profile for BIND 9 is designed to work with the above (quoted) configuration.